# parsequery custom listview

Tags: android-listview, parse-platform

I have a login and signup screen (activity) built. The next will be a list view (it is a social app and will be similar to Facebook or Twitter). I can get my data from Parse just fine (in the form of `IEnumerable<ParseObject>`).

How do I take that data and pass it over to a custom adapter to populate the list view?

About the most success I've has was for the list to populate with `ParseObject.object`.
That is literally what the list said. Should I be using something other than `ParseObject.GetQuery`?